# existing thread in a threadpool creates a new thread using new Thread().start()

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have created a threadpool in java with a core pool size of 40.

Suppose currently it has only 10 threads. If one of the threads belonging to this threadpool creates some new threads, will they be part of this threadpool only or will they be independent?

Answer (score 0):

The newly created threads should not be part of it. If you are using ThreadPool by the executor service then You have to submit even the child threads to be part of the ThreadPool of this executor service.

Answer (score 0):

Your short answer is **NO**, extra threads spawned from tasks submitted to a thread pool wouldn't be counted as part of pool capacity since you are not explicitly submitting or asking thread pool to start it.

In other words, pool is not tracking running status of that spawned thread. Programmer is creating thread instance and starting it.

Also, for Java Thread Pools , capacity is about number of **RUNNING** tasks at a particular point in time and a task is a `RUNNABLE` or  `CALLABLE` so you can always **SUBMIT** more than pool - capacity tasks to a pool but don't ask to run more than capacity tasks at any point of time.